# Calculate one sql query as the percentage of another?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by, percentage

I am trying to calculate the percentage of jobs shipped late. I have come up with the following query:

```
SELECT 
COUNT(dbo.Jobs.jmpJobID) AS "Jobs Shipped" 
FROM
 ((dbo.Jobs 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.SalesOrderJobLinks ON dbo.Jobs.jmpJobID = dbo.SalesOrderJobLinks.omjJobID) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.SalesOrderLines ON dbo.SalesOrderJobLinks.omjSalesOrderID = dbo.SalesOrderLines.omlSalesOrderID AND omjSalesOrderLineID = omlSalesOrderLineID)    
WHERE  dbo.Jobs.jmpCompletedDate  >=  '{%Last Monday Date YYYYMMDD%}' AND dbo.Jobs.jmpCompletedDate  <  '{%Next Saturday Date YYYYMMDD%}'

UNION

SELECT COUNT(dbo.Jobs.jmpJobID) AS "Late Jobs" 
FROM ((dbo.Jobs 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.SalesOrderJobLinks ON dbo.Jobs.jmpJobID = dbo.SalesOrderJobLinks.omjJobID) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.SalesOrderLines ON dbo.SalesOrderJobLinks.omjSalesOrderID = dbo.SalesOrderLines.omlSalesOrderID AND omjSalesOrderLineID = omlSalesOrderLineID)    
WHERE  dbo.Jobs.jmpCompletedDate  >=  '{%Last Monday Date YYYYMMDD%}' AND dbo.Jobs.jmpCompletedDate  <  '{%Next Saturday Date YYYYMMDD%}' AND dbo.Jobs.jmpCompletedDate  >  dbo.Jobs.jmpProductionDueDate
```

This returns the total jobs shipped and the total shipped late as separate rows in one column. 
eg. 10 shipped, 5 shipped late.

Any ideas for how I can do this as a percentage, coming up with a result of 50%?

Many thanks, appreciate any comments!

Comment: Why so many parentheses in the `FROM` clause? Maybe you are running ms-access, not sql-server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT 
    AVG(CASE 
        WHEN j.jmpCompletedDate > j.jmpProductionDueDate THEN 100.0 
        ELSE 0.0 
    END) AS PercentJobsLate 
FROM dbo.Jobs j 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.SalesOrderJobLinks oj 
    ON j.jmpJobID = oj.omjJobID
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.SalesOrderLines o 
    ON oj.omjSalesOrderID = o.omlSalesOrderID 
    AND omjSalesOrderLineID = omlSalesOrderLineID    
WHERE  
    j.jmpCompletedDate >= '{%Last Monday Date YYYYMMDD%}' 
    AND j.jmpCompletedDate < '{%Next Saturday Date YYYYMMDD%}'
```

Note that I modified your query as follows:

- there is no needs for nested parentheses around the `JOIN`s in SQL Server (only ms-access requires this)
- table aliases make the queries easier to write, read and maintain

Comment: If you use `100` instead of `1` in the `AVG` expression you will get a percentage instead of a fraction.

Comment: @GMB - one more thing, seeing as you are a genius! Where does the ROUND go in the query?